# How to send an empty array to PHP server using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I need to receive a PHP empty array via a `form-data`  request. The notation  expected from the body by the PHP server is this: `filters[]`. But when I send an empty array from JS I receive this `filters: ""`.

My sending method:

```
 var filters = new Array();
 var body = "filters="+filters;
 request.send(body);
```

So, there's a way to acomplish that naturally in Javascript?

Comment: Why not jquery and ajax ?

Answer (score 1):

Small change could work for you

```
var filters = new Array();
var body = "filters[]="+filters; //added [] to filters
request.send(body);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create an array with an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Best possible method is converting array/json to string using

```
var dataAsString = JSON.stringify(array);
```

then from string you have to retrieve array in PHP.
Refer [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to know how to convert String back to JSON.

Comment: Using this method my request send data in the following way: ``filters: "[]"``. Not exactly as expected: ``filters[]``.

Comment: Well, sorry then.. As far as I know there is no other natural way to accomplish this in JS.

Comment: If you just need an option for this array you could possibly do (HOT FIX, NOT A PROPER SOLUTION) "filters["+(filters.length > 0 ? filters.toString() : "")+"]";

Answer (score 0):

The URL Parameters should look like this:

```
http://example.com/?filter[]=1&filter[]=2
```

Or

```
http://example.com/?filter[0]=1&filter[1]=2
```

etc

As an alternative you could JSON encode a parameter, but then using POST parameters would be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by sending with the given notation:

```
if (!filters || filters.length === 0) {
    filters = [""];
}
```

When the filters are empty. And an object when the filters are not empty.